# Use of Xilinx_Out32 for specific nibble set

Tags: xilinx

Is there a Xilinx internal function that may allow the set/reset of specific nibble component without disturbing the other nibbles in a given 32 bit AXI-lite Memory mapped 32-bit data width. 
Example: -
Addr || Data 
0x01 || 0x00110011
0x01 || 0x0"1"110011 - only setting of the second nibble from the MSB position

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `xil_io.h`. There is no such function available. So you have to write this function. Please take a look at this untested example.

```
static INLINE void Xil_OutNibble32(UINTPTR Addr, u8 Nibble, u8 Value)
{
    // Get the old value
    u32 temp = Xil_In32(Addr);

    // Clear/set the addressed nibble
    if(Value)
    {
        temp |= (0x0F << Nibble);
    }
    else
    {
        temp &= ~(0x0F << Nibble);
    }

    // Write the new value
    Xil_Out32(Addr, temp);
}
```